# Subscribe to Microsoft Office 365 Management Activity API: Authorization denied

Tags: python, azure, python-requests, jwt, office365api

I try to subscribe to Office 365 Management API and fail.

posting to https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/{tennant-id}/activity/feed/sub
scriptions/start?contentType=Audit.SharePoint
Returns with the following error:

```
<Response [401]> {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

When using local python environment.
I already have access Token, which I use it to print the office 365 root website and connect to Azure Active Directory.
I suspected the error was in the way I created the Microsoft azure web app, therefore I created a new azure web-app which ended with the same result, also when I creating “Native Client app” ended with the same result.
When I use an 'web app python console', for exampl 'pythonanywhere', an exception is being thron, with the following error:
“Cannot connect to proxy. Socket error: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden.”

I followed Microsoft Manual: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt227394.aspx#StartSubscription

Sample of my code:

```
tid = {my tenant ID}
subscriptionHeader = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; utf-8' , 'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % (access_token)}
subscriptionBody = {"webhook" : {
       "address": {my site} } }
subscribtionPostUrl = "https*://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/%s/activity/feed/subscriptions/start?contentType=Audit.SharePoint" %(tid)
print ("posting to %s\n" % (subscribtionPostUrl) )
subscribtionPost = requests.post(subscribtionPostUrl, data=subscriptionBody, headers=subscriptionHeader)
print ("subscribtionPost %s\n" % (subscribtionPost ) )
print ("subscribtionPost %s\n" % (subscribtionPost.text ) )
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and the solution was to use https://manage.office.com as a resource when you ask for the token (and NOT https://manage.office.com/ - note the forward slash at the end, you should not include it...)

Comment: This was my issue as well. The request for the JWT succeeds with both:
`https://manage.office.com/` and `https://manage.office.com`, but subsequent use of the generated token with the trailing slash fails.

If MS knew what they were doing, and `https://manage.office.com/` is truly an invalid resource, then the JWT request for it should fail.

In contrast, if `https://manage.office.com/` IS a valid resource, then authentication attempts with this permutation should succeed.

{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."} is opaque and unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

According your error message:

> {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}

It seems your Azure AD application doesn't have enough permission for this operation. You can try to run following powershell script to upgrade your AD application's permission:

```
#use the administrator account to sign in 
Connect-MsolService
$ClientIdWebApp = '{your_AD_application_client_id}'
$webApp = Get-MsolServicePrincipal –AppPrincipalId $ClientIdWebApp
#use Add-MsolRoleMember to add it to “Company Administrator” role).
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleName "Company Administrator" -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal -RoleMemberObjectId $webApp.ObjectId
```

And meanwhile, every access_token will expire in 3600 seconds, and during my test, I will reproduce your issue only when my access_token has expired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
Where should I run this script from? 
It seems I need to run this script from azure when I am connected with the specific Azuee AD user which I want to elavate his permissions?

Comment: I manged to solved this:
The problem was in the resource I was trying to access.
After re-writing the code following the documantation, 
I successfully recieved this answer:

<Response [200]>
{"contentType":"Audit.SharePoint","status":"enabled","webhook":null}
Will manage to continue from here,
Thanks  for your help.